# Mounting SD card with executable permissions. (Looking for a specific command)

Tags: mount, xfce, steam, sd-card, executable

I installed linux on my chromebook to play some games because my rig is fried atm. Last night I successfully mounted my sd card with executable permissions to function as a steam library. I used a specific command that I think I found on this site (browsing on my phone) and I had to uninstall and reinstall linux and now I'm back to square one. This command was the only one that worked and I can't find the page in my search history to save my life.

It was something like : umount -o remount,exec /dev/sd or /media/removable/SD\ Card or both.

I'm new to linux so I'm having trouble troubleshooting based on the errors I'm getting. If someone knows what I'm talking about and can correct me it would be much appreciated.

Again it's the only one that worked.

Answer (score 2):

Found it. Wasn't on this site.

```
mount -o remount,exec /dev/sd
```